# JSLint Character Unexpected '.'

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jslint

Atoms's JSLint report is complaining about an unexpected dot of the .toFixed function:

```
subTotal = (Math.round(subTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```

> at line 113, character 50 Unexpected '.'

The code works fine,

Question: Is this a fault with JSLint or have I coded something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jslint doesn't like the dot "." after a naked, parenthesized expression.  adding a `Number` in front of `(` should fix the warning.  the other common-case is adding a `String` in front of `(`.

```
subTotal = Number(Math.round(subTotal * 100) / 100).toFixed(2);
```